# How to post a foreign key using as an actual field name and not pk value

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm still new to Django and I'm trying to post the `rfid` number and bus `reg` number and I am getting following error **:**

> {"status":"error","data":{"rfid":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value,
> received str."],"bus":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received
> str."]}}

I would like to post the actual `rfid` number and bus `reg` number instead of the `pk` value. Is there any way of achieving this ?

**Transaction model :**

```html
class Transaction(models.Model):
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    rfid = models.ForeignKey(Rfid, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

**Serializer:**

```html
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('rfid', 'bus')
```

**views.py:**

```html
class TransactionViews(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, 
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, 
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**rfid model:**

```html
class Rfid(models.Model):
    rfid_num = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    lock = models.BooleanField(choices = BOOL_CHOICES, default = False, verbose_name = 'Lock card', blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**bus model:**

```html
class Bus(models.Model):
    reg_num = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, `request.data` has a string representation of the primary keys from rfid and bus.

```
Error: {"status":"error","data":{"rfid":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."],"bus":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]}}
```

Check what dictionary `request.data` is returning in your **views.py** and try to convert the primary keys to integer values before passing them to your serializer object.

```
class TransactionViews(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        data = request.data
        data['rfid'] = int(data['rfid'])
        data['bus'] = int(data['bus'])
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=data)
```

Comment: {'bus': 'AEX4444', 'rfid': 'hbesbg4342'}  this is the dictionary being returned and i get an error that says it expected a pk value and got str. Is there any way of posting those actual rfid number and reg number instead of the pk value.

Comment: There is no way of posting the numbers if the request does not provide them. Where and how is the request generated?

Comment: This is what i want to post--->curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transaction/ -d "{\"bus\":\"AEX4444\",\"rfid\":\"hbesbg4342\"}" which contains the actual fields instead of---->curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transaction/ -d "{\"bus\":\"1\",\"rfid\":\"1\"}" which contains the pk values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create Rfid and Bus objects with the values in `TransactionViews`  before creating the `Transaction` object, try the code written below, in `views.py` file

```
class TransactionViews(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        bus_reg_no = request.data.get('bus')
        bus = Bus.objects.get_or_create(reg_num = bus_reg_no)
        data['bus'] = bus
        rfid_no = request.data.get('rfid')
        rfid = Rfid.objects.get_or_create(rfid_num = rfid_no)
        data['rfid'] = rfid
        serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, 
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, 
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```